# Test if NeoVim was opened with file in lua

Tags: lua, vim-plugin, neovim

I'm creating a plugin for NeoVim in Lua, and I only want to do a certain thing if NeoVim
was opened without opening a file

So for example, if I invoke NeoVim with `nvim file.txt`, the code should execute, because I'm opening a file. However, if I ran `nvim`, it should not execute.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

neovim has a builtin function `argv()` which returns a list of files passed to neovim.

```
if next(vim.fn.argv()) ~= nil then
  -- neovim was opened with files
end
```

more info: `:h argv()`